# Why is this object coming up as "unknown class" in this ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, arraylist

Created some public static objects in a class and want to place them into an ArrayList. When I use the .add() method to add the objects to the list, I'm getting an error that the class of the object is unknown. I'll use books to make it easy to see.

I want to house all my books and the lists of books actually in the Book class, so my main class doesn't get too filled up with them. That's why i've made them public and static - so I can just call them when I need them.

The code for compiling the list works just fine in the main method, but for some reason when I bring it over to the Book class it gives me the underline on bookA, bookB, and bookC with the error "Unknown Class"

```
import.java.List;
import.java.ArrayList;

public class Book {
    String title;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public static Book bookA = new Book("Book A");
    public static Book bookB = new Book("Book B");
    public static Book bookC = new Book("Book C"); 

    public static List<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    myBooks.add(bookA);
    myBooks.add(bookB);
    myBooks.add(bookC);

}
```

Comment: Are the static variables of type `Book`?  You haven't specified a type in your code example.

Comment: Did you mean `public static bookA = new Book("Book A");`?

Comment: or even `public static Book bookA = new Book("Book A");`...?

Comment: @blafasel  fixed those things here - had them right on my personal code. Thanks.

Comment: @Reimus it's correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs to be in a method or in a `static` block

```
static{
    myBooks.add(bookA);
    myBooks.add(bookB);
    myBooks.add(bookC);
}
// or static method
public static void main(String[] args){
    myBooks.add(bookA);
    myBooks.add(bookB);
    myBooks.add(bookC);
}
```

Comment: The static block worked for me! thanks, still wrapping my head around the whole main(String[] args) { thing.

Comment: @Jonathan The main method is the method to be able to execute a code, a program, without a method with this signature you won't be able to launch anuthing

Comment: @Jonathan  don’t hesitate to accept the answer if it’s ok for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the creation of objects and addition of them to a list, to a method inside the class Book. Java doesn't allow random code inside a class.

For example:

`myBooks.add(bookA);
 myBooks.add(bookB);
 myBooks.add(bookC);`

They need to be in a method.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class GlobalBookcase {

    public static List<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public GlobalBookcase(){
        myBooks.add(new Book("Book A"));
        myBooks.add(new Book("Book B"));
        myBooks.add(new Book("Book C"));
    }
}


public class Book {
    String title;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't [imported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: had it on my personal code, forgot it here. Thanks.